# How to pass HTML element in view to controller class

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

How to pass HTML element in view to controller class. ?

my ViewModel :

```
 public class NewsViewModel
    {
        [AllowHtml]
        public virtual string Body { get; set; }
    }
```

i try to pass any HTML element in form. i get below output.

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (Body="<p>stackoverflow</p>...").
```

why ?

updated :

action

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> Create(NewsViewModel viewModel)
{
   //...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the `virtual` ?

Comment: yes. but does not worked

Comment: How does your action method(HttpPost) looks like ? the parameters

Comment: This code should work fine. I verified in an mvc 5 project and it works fine with default configurations.

Comment: my solution in web.config : `    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" requestValidationMode="2.0"  />`. then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [ValidateInput(false)] on your action.

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Create(string comment)
{
    ...
}
```